# How to run a 125,000 btu pool heater from a 15,000 generator

Tags: wiring

I want to connect a pool heater and want the power source to come from my generator. The wire setup on the pool heater is L N G but the wires are black red green. [image]

Comment: so it is a 240 volt (2 phases), GAS heater

Comment: How many watts is the heater?  A generator is usually quite expensive to use instead of your local power company(in most places).

Comment: Can you provide a wiring diagram for the heater and specs for the generator?

Comment: 15,000 watts is the generator and has its own breaker switch.

Comment: Good size generator, but what watts is the heater.  So far heater seems to be two hots and ground, no neutral.  Generator should have a receptacle with two hots, a neutral and ground.  Cap off the neutral with a wire nut and you should be good to empty your pocket book running the generator.

Comment: One the pool heater it's says L N G but the diagram show L1 L2 G

Comment: 15,000 watts duel fuel generator

Comment: 125,000 BTU/hr equals over 36000 watts.  A 15000 watt generator is not nearly big enough for the load.

Comment: For a max load of power 70 amp. I wanna do the minimum which is 50 amp.

Comment: I don't think this dog is going to hunt! as the old saying goes.  Why on earth would you power an electrical resistant pool heater with a generator?  A purely gas (L N G) heater would be FAR more efficient.  If you don't have power at the pool, a very small generator could power the pumps needed, it would pay back to convert in energy savings in short order .

Comment: How much power will the pool heater consume?  If the title is correct then the generator is far too small.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  I believe the "L N G" comment is in reference to "line neutral ground", not "liquid natural gas".  This is not likely safe because of a mismatch of voltage, someone could easily get electrocuted.  Someone needs to call a licensed electrician.  Maybe this system will work with line voltage at 230 volts, and maybe also at a 115-0-115 split voltage.  I'm not even sure what question is being asked.

Comment: @ChrisUrbina -- why do you want to run your pool heater, of all things, from your generator?

Comment: Using a generator to heat a pool is completely nonsensical. A generator turns about 1/3 of the fuels energy into electricity and sends the rest out the exhaust. Burning the fuel in a heat exchanger you can easily get over 90% efficiency.

Comment: @MacGuffin   you could be right, that's the issue with using too many abbreviations.

Comment: @whatsisname  TOTALLY AGREE,  crazy idea to use an electrical resistance pool heater powered by a generator.   Just think of (as you mentioned) the amount of energy going out the exhaust, not to to mention the cooling needed for the engine itself.   This is a terrible idea.

Comment: +1 @whatsisname, a burner heater would use much less fuel! Or if the generator is water cooled, power the house with it and put a heat exchanger to heat the pool with the waste heat from the engine...

Comment: Why do you say "The wire setup on the pool heater is L N G".  Does it say that on the heater somewhere, or are you saying that because the incoming wires are black, white, and bare?

Answer (score 2):

### Not likely... even with a heat pump

While heat pump pool heaters are more efficient than electric resistance heaters, they aren't more efficient *by enough* to make this heater work on that generator.

Generators are not perfect and expecting to successfully load the generator to 100% *continuously* is not a good plan. So you should plan to take only about 10,000 watts for the pool. heating load.

If we used resistive heaters (COP 1.0) then 125,000 BTU takes 36,600 watts or 152 amps. For that to happen in 10,000 watts, your heat pump would need a COP of 3.66.

Is it *possible* to build a heat pump capable of 3.66 COP?  The more modern units can easily beat that, *but it depends what the interchange (outdoor / underground) temperature is*.  With a good ground-source loop or well-water arrangement, it could probably happen.  But if the heat pump is air-sourced, forget it. Cold weather will degrade the COP and stall the generator.

However, we don't get to make such wild guesses. The Electrical Code addresses this in black and white, and we must follow it.

### Generators must be sufficient *for the load to be served*

And "the load to be served" is decided by one thing: the nameplate of the machine.  It will have a nameplate calling out power requirements in watts, amps or VA.  It may state LRA (Locked Rotor Amperage) if it's a simpler heat pump.

Whatever it states on the nameplate, **the generator must be large enough to supply it**.   So the amps or VA stated on the heat pump nameplate will decide for you what the minimum generator size is.

And that's that.

Comment: harp  I think it was pretty clear that using that large a generator, the OP intended electrical resistance heating, even though it's a large generator, as you and others have said, it's still way too small for the intended use.     I won't DV your answer, but I do disagree.   Until we know if the pool heater is gas or electric, any answers are speculative at best.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Per the schematic, this is a heat pump. CM=compressor motor, FM=fan motor, 4-way valve, fan defrosting all equate with heat pump.

Comment: @MTA   Thanks, at least now this makes some more sense. Still, powering up a large compressor via a generator is not efficient.   But its apparent that the OP has a considerable investment that would be hard to walk away from and replace with gas.   Thanks again for the interpretation of the wiring diagram, I'm not good with HVAC stuff and missed that it was a heat pump style heater.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson No. Just no. There is no way a 125K BTU home pool heater is electric resistance. As the answer shows, it would use an *entire* 200A service all by itself.

Comment: @nobody  thanks for the resp. according to MTA it's a heat pump style heater.  I maintain than running a generator to power a heat pump isn't very efficient, Pure natural gas would be most efficient, but  the OP probably has a lot invested in his current setup that he's not willing to walk away from it.   He'll have a big fuel bill.  

Lastly, we can't assume that the OP has any idea of what the true requirements are, all he asked was how to "hook it up".   I made the incorrect assumption it was resistance, I stand corrected.

Comment: @George OK I didn't see that at the time. It was a winner with gas, a loser with resistance electric and a weak wobbler with a heat pump. Translation: it fails on the first cold day.  Total rewrite.